# InAppSettingsKit: How to customize the individual titles of added items from a PSChildPaneSpecifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, inappsettingskit

I'm using [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit) to create a section in my app's in-app settings where the user can add a number of custom items, each of which has its own set of properties (a string value and an int value).

To do this, I'm following the example mentioned in the docs under the heading [Extending Child Panes](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit#extending-child-panes), and demonstrated in the [InAppSettingsKit sample app](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit/tree/master/InAppSettingsKitSampleApp), where in my Root.plist, a dictionary item with an `AddSpecifier` of type `PSChildPaneSpecifier` is added, pointing to a child plist file with each item's individual properties.

This works great; except for that each user-added item appears in the main settings display with the exact same name. (Namely, whatever value is in the Root.plist in the `AddSpecifier` dictionary's `key` child element; I'm currently using the value "Tag", following the example in the sample app.)

[image: InAppSettingsKit view, with three PSChildPaneSpecifier items added by the user]

Obviously, it would be hard for the user of my app to distinguish between any of these identically-named items, in order to edit the properties of a particular one of them.

How can I customize the displayed titles for each of these individual user-added `PSChildPaneSpecifier` items?

Ideally, I'd like the name for each of these user-added items displayed on the main IASK settings page to match the user-entered string-type title that the user entered for that item on the child pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that in the `ItemSpecifier` dictionary element (sibling to the `AddSpecifier` dictionary with type `PSChildPaneSpecifier`), I had inadvertently omitted the `Key` child element.

Adding to my `ItemSpecifier` dictionary a child element named `Key` with type String and value set to the same value as the `Key` value in my child `plist` file of the String-type element whose user-entered value I wanted to have show up as the name of the element in my main IASK settings page did the trick.